# Won't boot Ubuntu, but will boot Windows

Tags: live-usb

I was booting Ubuntu Gnome from a usb, using mkusb to make another one. When I restarted and booted into the new one, I got this error:

```
error: disk 'hd0,4' not found.  
alloc magic is broken at XXXXXXXX 
Aborted. Press any key to continue.
```

I tried to boot back into the original one, and it gave the same error.
I booted back to Windows 10 fine, so it's not a hardware issue. I plugged in a different Ubuntu usb and was able to boot to it successfully. What's the problem? How do I fix it? Are Ubuntu usbs even stable (when compared to an actual install), I keep running into all sorts of errors with them?